# How do I find a node knowing its URL?

Tags: nodes, uri

I need to rename the node home-care/vids into home-care/product-solutions. The trouble is that I can't find home-care/vids in the dashboard of this relatively big site.

How can I find it?

I have even done a MySQL database search but results are not helpful for me.

Comment: Your title isn't very helpful to identify the question. Please consider fixing that.

Comment: Any reason you can't go to `home-care/vids` and press edit?

Comment: `drupal_goto(drupal_get_normal_path('home-care/vids') . '/edit');`

Comment: Argh, the question was edited within the grace period, so it doesn't count as an edit, and now I can't reverse my vote. :(

Comment: @Clive: Because I don't see Edit button/link

Comment: Are you sure this is in fact a node and not say, for example, a page generated by Views? The only reason I ask is the names suggest lists of things. If this is in fact the case, you can go into your Views admin pages (admin/build/views/list here in D6landia) and search for it.

Comment: I'm sorry to be picky Jimajamma, but that's mostly speculation. The provider could be _any_ module with a hook_implementation, and not just Views. (Although admittedly View is statistically rather likely)

Comment: @Letharion Now you can change your vote.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is almost always to visit the page you want to change, and hit the "Edit" button among the tabs.

However, sometimes this may not be practical for whatever reason. SQL-queries below:

**D6**

`SELECT src FROM url_alias WHERE dst = 'home-care/vids';`

**D7**

`SELECT source FROM url_alias WHERE alias = 'home-care/vids';`

You may in both version want to add `AND language =` if your site is multilingual.

Comment: D7:
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: I don't see Edit button. The site was delivered to us by an other programmers team and we don't know everything they did before

Comment: Then it's not a node as stated in your question, but a hook_menu implementation. That's out of scope for this question now, but I guess you could open a separate one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your theme's page.tpl.php and print the TABS, that may be ommited

and

```
<?php if ($tabs): ?>
    <div class="tabs">
      <?php print render($tabs); ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

If you have the appropriate permissions, the tabs will come up and you can visit the edit of that node